# Design pattern for subclass-like structure

Tags: haskell, design-patterns, pattern-matching, typeclass

My goal is to represent a set of types with a similar behaviour in a elegant and performant manner. To achieve this, I have created a solution that utilises a single type, followed by a set of functions that perform pattern matching.

My first question is: is there a way how to represent the same ideas using a single type-class and instead of having a constructor per each variation to have a type that implements said type-class?

Which of the two approaches below is:
 - a better recognised design pattern in Haskell?
 - more memory efficient?
 - more performant?
 - more elegant and why?
 - easier to use for consumers of the code?

### Approach 1: Single type and pattern matching

Suppose there is a following structure:

```hs
data Aggregate a
  = Average    <some necessary state keeping>
  | Variance   <some necessary state keeping>
  | Quantile a <some necessary state keeping>
```

It's constructors are not public as that would expose the internal state keeping. Instead, a set of constructor functions exist:

```hs
newAverage :: Floating a
  => Aggregate a
newAverage = Average ...

newVariance :: Floating a
  => Aggregate a
newVariance = Variance ...

newQuantile :: Floating a
  => a                     -- ! important, a parameter to the function
  -> Aggregate a
newQuantile p = Quantile p ...
```

Once the object is created, we can perform two functions: `put` values into it, and once we are satisfied, we can `get` the current value:

```hs
get :: Floating a
  => Aggregate a
  -> Maybe a
get (Average <state>) = getAverage <state>
get (Variance <state>) = getVariance <state>
get (Quantile _ <state>) = getQuantile <state>

put :: Floating a
  => a
  -> Aggregate a
  -> Aggregate a
put newVal (Average <state>) = putAverage newVal <state>
put newVal (Variance <state>) = putVariance newVal <state>
put newVal (Quantile p <state>) = putQuantile newVal p <state>
```

### Approach 2: Type-classes and instances

```hs
class Aggregate a where
  new :: a
  get :: Floating f => a f -> Maybe f
  put :: Floating f => 

data Average a = Average Word64 a
data Variance a ...

instance Aggregate Average where

instance Aggregate Variance where

instance Aggregate Quantile where
```

The obvious problem here is the fact that `new` is not parametric and thus `Quantile` can't be initialised with the `p` parameter. Adding a parameter to `new` is possible, but it would result in all other non-parametric constructors to ignore the value, which is not a good design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the "codata" encoding, which sounds like it might be the best fit for your problem.

```
data Aggregate a = Aggregate 
    { get :: Maybe a
    , put :: a -> Aggregate a
    }

-- Use the closure to keep track of local state.
newAverage :: (Floating a) => Aggregate a
newAverage = Aggregate { get = Nothing, put = go 0 0 }
    where
    go n total x = Aggregate { get = Just ((total + x) / (n+1))
                             , put = go (n+1) (total+x)
                             }

-- Parameters are not a problem.
newQuantile :: (Floating a) => a -> Aggregate a
newQuantile p = Aggregate { get = ... ; put = \x -> ... }

...
```

For some reason this approach always slips under the radar of people with OO backgrounds, which is strange because it is a pretty close match to that paradigm.

Comment: Not just a close match to the paradigm; it is also a close analogue to how many OO languages implement their object system. The set of functions associated with the type are its "vtable", allowing for dispatch to any number of "subclass" implementations.

Comment: What's the behaviour of this solution with respect to laziness? Wouldn't the new `Aggregate` instance create a new thunk upon each invocation?

Comment: This is really interesting, as you have completely avoided using ADTs to represent the different choice and essentially you lock the user in their choice of aggregate, which is really clever. Is this solution more performant as there is no pattern matching that needs to be performed?

Comment: @DanielLovasko, with each call to `put` a closure (not quite the same as a thunk) is created.  And thunks for `n+1` and `total+x` will also be created, but you could make those strict.  In fact if you put in a lot of data before `get`ting, you should make those strict so you don't get thunk buildup: `go !n !total x = ...`

Comment: @DanielLovasko, Of course you should always use measurements to assess performance; however I don't suspect the performance of this to be significantly different from the ADT solution (as long as you avoid the thunk buildup problem)––they are almost the same thing, except this uses a closure call instead of a pattern match.  danidiaz's solution is the same as this, except, because it avoids recursion, the optimizer might have an easier time with it (the optimizer can't always "flatten" recursive abstractions because they might diverge).

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to give a general recommendation. I tend to prefer approach 1. Note that you could use

```
data Aggregate a
  = Average    AverageState
  | Variance   VarianceState
  | Quantile a QuantileState
```

and export every constructor above, keeping only the `...State` types private to the module.

This might be feasible in some contexts, but not in others, so it has to be evaluated on a case by case basis.

About approach 2, this could be more convenient if you have many constructors / types around. To fix the `new` problem, one could use type families (or fundeps) as in

```
class Floating f => Aggregate a f where
  type AggregateNew a f
  new :: AggregateNew a f -> a f
  get :: a f -> Maybe f
  put :: ...

instance Floating f => Aggregate Average f where
  type AggregateNew (Average a) f = ()
  new () = ...

instance Floating f => Aggregate Quantile f where
  type AggregateNew (Quantile a) f = a
  new x = ...
```

The naming above is horrible, but I used it to make the point. `new` takes an argument of type `AggregateNew k f` which can be `()` if `new` needs no information, or some more informative type when it is needed, like `a` for creating a `Quantile`.

Comment: Would this approach become "cleaner" if we removed the `new` function from the type class and have something like this: `data Quantile a = Quantile a <state>`, with a constructor method `quantile :: Floating f => f -> Quantile f` and then only define `get` and `put` for each? Now that I am thinking about this further: wouldn't this approach prevent having something like a `Data.Map` of `String -> Aggregate` since it is not a single type? I think that is a drawback worthy of mentioning.

Comment: @DanielLovasko Yes, that's a drawback which could be overcome with existential types, but in such case we fall into this antipattern: https://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/

Answer (score 2):

There is a third approach for defining “aggregators” that neither requires an inextensible  sum type nor multiple datatypes + a typeclass.

**Approach 3: Single-constructor datatype that puts state behind an existential**

Consider this type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
data Fold a b = forall x. Fold (x -> a -> x) x (x -> b)
```

It represents an aggregator that ingests values of type `a` and eventually "returns" a value of type `b` while carrying an internal state `x`.

The constructor has type `(x -> a -> x) -> x -> (x -> b) -> Fold a b`. It takes a step function, an initial state and a final "summary" function. Notice that the state is decoupled from the return value `b`. They can be the same, but it's not required.

Also, the state is [existentially quantified](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=existentialquantification#extension-ExistentialQuantification). We know the type of the state when we create a `Fold`, and we can work with it when we pattern-match on the `Fold`—in order to feed it data through the step function—but it's not reflected in the `Fold`'s type. We can put `Fold` values with different inner states in the same container without problems, as long as they ingest and return the same types.

This pattern is sometimes called a “beautiful fold”. There is a library called [foldl](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/foldl) that is based on it, and provides may premade folds and utility functions.

The [`Fold`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/foldl-1.4.5/docs/Control-Foldl.html) type in [foldl](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/foldl) has many useful instances. In particular, the `Applicative` instance lets us create composite folds that still traverse the input data a single time, instead of requiring multiple passes.

Comment: Just want to mention that this is equivalent in expressivity to my codata version (`Aggregator a ~ Fold a (Maybe a)`), though i think `Fold`s are easier for the compiler to optimize because they are non recursive.  In fact, TIL every recursive type `Mu f` has an equivalent non-recursive existential version `∃s. s × (s → f s)` (when `f` is a `Functor`).

Comment: I am definitely aware that the problem I am describing is similar to a fold, but is my thinking correct to say that this wouldn't allow intermediate `get` of the value, only once the fold is completed?

Comment: @DanielLovasko, that's not correct, it *is* possible to get intermediate values by repeatedly sending the intermediate states to the observer function. [Here is an example](https://gist.github.com/luqui/ed51bd523e025a5f4b98feaffcdec8f6).

Comment: @luqui Is there a paper or post that explains the equivalence of the recursive and existential versions?

Comment: @DanielLovasko To extract intermediate values, besides converting the fold into a scan like @luqui explains, another option would be to use the `duplicate :: Fold a b -> Fold a (Fold a b)` function from `Comonad`. The idea is that it lets you run a `Fold` with partial input. You can then keep feeding the resulting `Fold` with additional input, extract the result right away, or both.

Comment: @danidiaz not that I know of; I was just messing around after reading your post and found a bijection